# How to upgrade bash to v4.0+ properly?

Tags: upgrade, bash

I'm on OS X 10.10.2 and

```
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

How to upgrade bash to v4.0+ properly?

Update:

After installing bash with pkgsrc

```
 pkgin install bash
```

I got newer bash but it isn't default:

```
$ which bash
/bin/bash
$ /usr/pkg/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

How to make the newer bash the default one?

Comment: Relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24632/24324

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend getting [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Then run `brew install bash`, it will install bash 4.3.33. It's the easiest and safest way.

Then add the path to the executable to `/etc/shells`. For example:

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Comment: I use pkgsrc.  So I just manually install bash?

Comment: Yes, just do that. If it works with pkgsrc. Then add the path to the executable to `/etc/shells`. For example, `/usr/local/bin/bash`.